# Is common write $\lim f(2)$ instead of $\underset{x \to 2}{\lim} f(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, notation

I didn't saw anyone writing like it, but is it understandable? If yes why anyone write $\lim f(2)$?

Comment: "$\lim f(n)$" would make me guess the [sequential limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence) $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}f(n)$, and not anything like $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to n}}f(x)$.

Comment: This is not a good way to write limits. For example, the definition of the derivative would become $\displaystyle f'(x) =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim \frac{f(x + 0) - f(x)}{0}$, which is very ambiguous.

Comment: It is simply wrong for the meaning that you intend. In context one might be able to guess what was meant, but you should not make readers have to guess.

Comment: It's likely to be understood,  but I wouldn't recommed it. This is mathematics, and logic is crucial, so we should make any assumptions we made very explicit.

Comment: With $\lim f(n)$ I was wanting to say, e.g. $\lim f(2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. One might say that $f(n)=\lim_{x\to n} f_1(x)$, where $f_1: \mathcal D(f) / \{n\}\mapsto \mathcal R(f)$ s.t. $f_1(x)=f(x)$ in order to extend a function $f_1$ on a domain $\mathcal D(f_1)$ piecewise across a larger domain $\mathcal D(f)$: $$f: \mathcal D(f)\mapsto \mathcal R(f) ,  f(x)=\begin{cases} f_1(x)  & x\in \mathcal D(f_1) & \\  \lim_{t\to x} f_1(t) & x\notin\mathcal D(f_1) \end{cases}$$

However, $\lim f(n)$ has no easily understandable meaning. It could be what you wish to convey, but, as the comments point out, it could also be $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)$.

Where notation is ambiguous, it's best to avoid it even at the cost of brevity and stick to more unambiguous notation.